# Install of Visual Studio Community Fails

Tags: visual-studio

Upon trying to install VS Community, Error 2203 was encountered? How do I fix this? All the permissions are correct in the temp folders and I have enough space in the drive so what is causing this?

```
Something went wrong with the install.

You can troubleshoot the package failures by:

    1. Search for solutions using the search URL below for each package failure
    2. Modify your selections for the affected workloads or components and then retry the installation
    3. Remove the product from your machine and then install again

If the issue has already been reported on the Developer Community, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, we encourage you to create a new issue so that other developers will be able to find solutions or workarounds. You can create a new issue from within the Visual Studio Installer in the upper-right hand corner using the "Provide feedback" button.

================================================================================

Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Msi,version=15.0.27019.1' failed to install.
    Search URL
        https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Msi;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=2203
    Details
        MSI: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Msi,version=15.0.27019.1\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Msi.msi, Properties:  REBOOT=ReallySuppress ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1  MSIFASTINSTALL="7"  VSEXTUI="1"  VS7.3643236F_FC70_11D3_A536_0090278A1BB8="Z:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community" 
        Return code: 1603
        Return code details: Fatal error during installation.
        Message Id: 2203
        Message Details: The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2203. 
    Log
        C:\Users\schul\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20180225230849_006_Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Msi.log
    Impacted workloads
        .NET desktop development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop,version=15.0.27102.0)
        Visual Studio core editor (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor,version=15.0.27128.1)
    Impacted components
        .NET desktop development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Prerequisites,version=15.0.27102.0)
        .NET Framework 4.6.1 development tools (Microsoft.Net.ComponentGroup.DevelopmentPrerequisites,version=15.0.27005.2)
        .NET Portable Library targeting pack (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.PortableLibrary,version=15.0.27019.1)
        .NET profiling tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DiagnosticTools,version=15.0.27005.2)
        Blend for Visual Studio (Microsoft.ComponentGroup.Blend,version=15.0.27005.2)
        C# and Visual Basic (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices,version=15.0.27019.1)
        ClickOnce Publishing (Microsoft.Component.ClickOnce,version=15.0.27019.1)
        Data sources and service references (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VisualStudioData,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Entity Framework 6 tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.EntityFramework,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Just-In-Time debugger (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Debugger.JustInTime,version=15.0.27005.2)
        Managed Desktop Workload Core (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ManagedDesktop.Core,version=15.0.27019.1)
        Text Template Transformation (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TextTemplating,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Visual Studio core editor (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor,version=15.0.26606.0)
```

RAW LOG FILE >> https://pastebin.com/waKme1Xb

Comment: is your system up to date?

Comment: Cant update due to error 2203 and various similar error codes